# How to solve "leverage browser caching show" on pagespeed?

Tags: caching, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

i've got 99/100 score in a site but there's a persistent message about Leverage Browser Caching that not allows me to get 100/100.

Someone knows how to solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code tells browsers what to cache and how long to remember it. It should be added to the top of your .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
</IfModule>
```